# Haskell Snap: query_ trouble

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I got trouble with ambiguous type when developing web app with Snap.

My code is

```
getUserByUsrnamePwd :: Handler HaskellCalendar HaskellCalendar ()
getUserByUsrnamePwd = do
    username <- getPostParam "username"
    password <- getPostParam "password"
    user <- query_ "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?" (username, password)
    liftIO $ print (user :: [User])
```

I got an error

```
Expected type: (Maybe ByteString, Maybe ByteString)
               -> Handler HaskellCalendar HaskellCalendar [User]
  Actual type: (Maybe ByteString, Maybe ByteString) -> [r0]
```

I really don't know why because according to API it should be (Maybe ByteString, Maybe ByteString) rather than (Maybe ByteString, Maybe ByteString) -> [r0]

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snaplet-sqlite-simple-0.4.5/docs/Snap-Snaplet-SqliteSimple.html), it looks like `query_` is only for queries that take no parameters. You want `query`.

Comment: Thank you. I just realized it as well. Cheers!